# Mysql; consultar registro por cantidad de horas

Tags: mysql, datetime

Buen dìa, me gustaría hacer una consulta en mysql que me traiga los registros de un tiempo determinado. Por ejemplo la consulta que hago me trae los horarios desde ahora, 10:30:00 hasta las las 10:30:00 de mañana,pero a mi me gustaria que desde el tiempo actual solo me tome las 3 proximas horas para reducir el numeros de registros consultados. 
Les comparto mi codigo para ver si alguien me puede ayudar. Desde ya muchas gracias

```
SELECT distinct
                         hd.horario_locgps_codigo
                        ,lgd.locgps_longitud
                        ,lgd.locgps_latitud
                        ,hp.horario_sentido
                        ,hp.horario_media_vuelta
                        ,hp.horario_id
                        ,lgd.locgps_nombre
                         ,hd.horario_hora_salida
                       FROM horario_final hd
                        LEFT JOIN localidad_gps lgd ON lgd.locgps_codigo = hd.horario_locgps_codigo AND lgd.locgps_codigo > ''
                        LEFT JOIN horario_cabecera on horc_id=hd.horario_id
                        LEFT JOIN localidad ld on ld.localidad_id = hd.horario_origen
                        LEFT JOIN vehiculoestado on ves_id_horario = horc_id
                     and ves_horario_fecha = date(now())
                        Left join horario_final hp on hp.horario_id = horc_id and hp.horario_locgps_codigo > ''
                        LEFT JOIN localidad_gps lgp ON lgp.locgps_codigo = hp.horario_locgps_codigo AND lgp.locgps_codigo > ''
                        where lgd.locgps_latitud is not null
                        and lgd.locgps_longitud is not null
                        and coalesce(upper(ld.localidad_desc_publica),'si') <> 'NO'
                        and coalesce(upper(hd.horario_leyenda),'si') <> 'NO'

                        and ves_serie is not null
                        and hp.horario_hora_salida >= time(now())
                        and (hp.horario_id =1503)order by hd.horario_locgps_codigo
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar las funciones `date_add()` y `now()` para lograr lo que quieres.

Por ejemplo, para ver aquellos registros cuya *hora de salida* está en las siguientes 3, he cambiado la condición `>=` por `between`:

```
SELECT distinct
         hd.horario_locgps_codigo
       , lgd.locgps_longitud
       , lgd.locgps_latitud
       , hp.horario_sentido
       , hp.horario_media_vuelta
       , hp.horario_id
       , lgd.locgps_nombre
       , hd.horario_hora_salida
  FROM horario_final hd
       LEFT JOIN localidad_gps lgd ON lgd.locgps_codigo = hd.horario_locgps_codigo AND lgd.locgps_codigo > ''
       LEFT JOIN horario_cabecera on horc_id=hd.horario_id
       LEFT JOIN localidad ld on ld.localidad_id = hd.horario_origen
       LEFT JOIN vehiculoestado on ves_id_horario = horc_id and ves_horario_fecha = date(now())
       Left join horario_final hp on hp.horario_id = horc_id and hp.horario_locgps_codigo > ''
       LEFT JOIN localidad_gps lgp ON lgp.locgps_codigo = hp.horario_locgps_codigo AND lgp.locgps_codigo > ''
 where lgd.locgps_latitud is not null
       and lgd.locgps_longitud is not null
       and coalesce(upper(ld.localidad_desc_publica),'si') <> 'NO'
       and coalesce(upper(hd.horario_leyenda),'si') <> 'NO'
       and ves_serie is not null
       and hp.horario_hora_salida between time(now()) and time(date_add(now(), interval 3 hour))
       and (hp.horario_id =1503)
 order by hd.horario_locgps_codigo
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo!!